# Can I import reports from another projects

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Someone know if can I import reports from another projects?   I'm in SSRS R2

Thanks a lots!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. Just right click on the project in Solution Expolorer and "Add -> Existing Item..." to add the .rdl from a previous project to the new one.

When making several reports with a similar style I usually create the first report: connect the datasource, set up a table with appropriate cell styles, add title text and page footers.

Then I "Add ->Existing Item..." and make a copy of the already added report in the Open Item dialog, then select the new duplicate and start with a half built report.